# Put PHP script in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I've some problem with this code. My code is error after i put some php in there. Here is my script now.

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('Nama Alat <select name="namaalat[]" id="textbox1" >
<option>--</option><option value="<?php echo $data[1]?>"><?php echo $data[1]?>
</option></select> Jumlah <input type="textbox" name="jml[]" id="textbox1">
Satuan<input type="textbox" name="satuan[]" id="textbox1" >');
```

before my script like this, and everything working fine

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('Jumlah <input type="textbox" name="jml[]" id="textbox1">
    Satuan<input type="textbox" name="satuan[]" id="textbox1" >');
```

then i put this code

```
Nama Alat <select name="namaalat[]" id="textbox1" >
<option>--</option><option value="<?php echo $data[1]?>"><?php echo $data[1]?>
</option></select>
```

and then it does not working.

everything is working now. I put put the php script that connecting to the database in wrong place .

```
$qr=mysql_query("select * from peralatan");
if(!$qr) {
            die("Gagal sob ! : Nih erronrnya disini -->  ".mysql_error());
            }
```

i put that script at bottom

Comment: Thanks for the information that your code is not working! If you would tell us what exactly are the errors, maybe we could even suggest you improvments.

Comment: Merge PHP with Javascript is dirty (one is client-side and the other server-side). Maybe you are looking to use Ajax.

Comment: Awesome Technique :p no wonder we learn every day

Comment: Show us what does the produced jQuery code look like and what error does PHP say, if any.

Comment: there isn't any error in PHP .

Comment: @Boby, show what gets generated (view source in browser). Show any js errors (javascript console in browser).

Comment: here the source -> http //justpaste it/etjs

Comment: Your generated code includes this: `<option value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: data in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\hamza\inputorderalat.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
">` You should look at this and it should help you debug your php.

Comment: @smerny i've fixed that, bro after i fixed that problem everything work great. My problem is, i put this code at the bottom of jquery script include "koneksi.php";

$msql="select * from peralatan";
$qr=mysql_query($msql);

$data=mysql_fetch_array($qr)

Comment: @Boby, see you just gotta take a little time to debug it sometimes and look at what the php generated compared to what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a guess but the javascript you're using, is that in a `.js` file by any chance?
if so then that's the problem, you can't call php from inside a `.js` file

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the file through a webserver that interprets the PHP. So if you are accessing the file through `file://`, you're doing it wrong (you need to access it through `http://`). Also, the file needs to have the extension `.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert php with javascript.

`php` is executed at server-side and `javascript` in client-side.

Comment: He doesnt want to insert PHP with JS, he wants the values of the HTML defined dynamically via PHP which is a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and JavaScript are executed at different "levels" let me say, because PHP is a server-side language and JavaScript is on the client side so mixing up the two is quite impossible. But if so, You may use the PHP SpiderMonkey PECL extension which allows you to embed the spidermonkey javascript engine in PHP. With this engine, you can embed javascript code and have them executed on the server-side You may download it from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey)

Comment: The PHP is executed ahead of time to supply data to the source at load time. PHP is not trying to be executed after page load.